# What is the best way to read then update in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to read a document from a collection, read its value, then if the value is <40 I need to increment the value.

Here is my current solution

```
let promise = db.collection('transactions').findOne(
        { _id: 'myid' }
    ).then(doc => {
        if (doc.count < 40) {
            ///update & increment doc.count
        }
        else {
            //do not increment
        }
    });
```

Does findOneAndModify allow for reading the document before modifying?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode this condition within the query and do a simple [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html):

```js
db.collection('transactions').updateOne(
    {_id: 'id', count: {$lt: 40}},
    {$inc: {count: 1}}
)
```

If you need to get the document (before or after the modification) simply use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/index.html):

```js
db.collection('transactions').findAndModify({
    query: {_id: 'id', count: {$lt: 40}},
    update: {$inc: {count: 1}},
    new: trueIfYouWantToGetTheModifiedVersion
})
```

Comment: In the first example, how do you determine if the item was incremented or not? How would you read other items in the document before you update?

Comment: If it match (therefore should update) you’ll find a document. If nothing matches (nothing to increment) it won’t find any document.

Comment: How can I determine if a document was found or not? Will need to direct the user based on if the document was able to increment.

Comment: It will return `null` if it finds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mongoing.com/docs/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate.html

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
       <filter>,
       <update>,
       {
         projection: <document>,
         sort: <document>,
         maxTimeMS: <number>,
         upsert: <boolean>,
         returnNewDocument: <boolean>,
         collation: <document>
       }
    )
```